# use dplyr to loop through models

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use an example using the library dplyr that I found to loop through a nonlinear model by factor level (StationID).  I keep getting an error message when I try to use the code with the nonlinear model.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(4)
data<-data.frame(group=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=3),res=c(rnorm(9,sd=1)),
covar=c(rnorm(9,sd=2)))

#make the dataframe a grouped by dataframe by variable group

by_cyl <- group_by(data, group)

#model
models <- by_cyl %>% do(mod = lm(res ~ covar, data = .))
models

#get model results
summarise(models, rsq = summary(mod)$r.squared)
models %>% do(data.frame(coef = coef(.$mod)))
models %>% do(data.frame(
  var = names(coef(.$mod)),
  coef(summary(.$mod)))
)
```

My model:

Sample of data.  The data are already grouped by StationID using group_by.

```
dput(sample_d)
structure(list(StationID = structure(c(94L, 315L, 421L, 133L, 
51L, 322L, 237L, 368L, 441L, 53L, 128L, 222L, 146L, 249L, 124L, 
95L, 176L, 403L, 247L, 383L, 404L, 330L, 99L, 105L, 66L), .Label = c("201501002", 
"201501003", "201501004", "201501005", "201501008", "201501009", 
"201501010", "201501011", "201501012", "201501013", "201501014", 
"201501015", "201501016", "201501017", "201501018", "201501019", 
"201501020", "201501023", "201501024", "201501025", "201501026", 
"201501027", "201501029", "201501030", "201501031", "201501033", 
"201501034", "201501035", "201501036", "201501037", "201501038", 
"201501039", "201501040", "201501042", "201501043", "201501044", 
"201501045", "201501046", "201501047", "201501048", "201501049", 
"201501050", "201501051", "201501052", "201501053", "201501054", 
"201501055", "201501056", "201501057", "201501058", "201501059", 
"201501060", "201501061", "201501062", "201501063", "201501066", 
"201501067", "201501068", "201501069", "201501070", "201501071", 
"201501072", "201501073", "201501074", "201501078", "201501079", 
"201501080", "201501081", "201501082", "201501083", "201501084", 
"201501086", "201501087", "201501088", "201501089", "201501090", 
"201501091", "201501092", "201501094", "201501095", "201501098", 
"201501099", "201501100", "201501101", "201501103", "201501105", 
"201501107", "201501108", "201501110", "201501111", "201501112", 
"201501117", "201501118", "201501119", "201501120", "201501122", 
"201501123", "201501125", "201501128", "201501129", "201501130", 
"201501133", "201501134", "201501137", "201501141", "201501142", 
"201501143", "201501144", "201501145", "201501146", "201501147", 
"201501150", "201501151", "201501152", "201501153", "201501155", 
"201501158", "201501159", "201501160", "201501161", "201501162", 
"201501163", "201501166", "201501172", "201501173", "201501174", 
"201501175", "201501179", "201501180", "201501181", "201501182", 
"201501184", "201501185", "201501186", "201501187", "201501188", 
"201501189", "201501190", "201501191", "201501192", "201501196", 
"201501197", "201501198", "201501199", "201501200", "201501201", 
"201501202", "201501203", "201501206", "201502001", "201502002", 
"201502003", "201502004", "201502005", "201502006", "201502011", 
"201502013", "201502014", "201502015", "201502016", "201502017", 
"201502019", "201502020", "201502021", "201502022", "201502023", 
"201502024", "201502025", "201502026", "201502027", "201502028", 
"201502029", "201502030", "201502031", "201502032", "201502033", 
"201502034", "201502037", "201502038", "201502039", "201502040", 
"201502041", "201502043", "201502044", "201502045", "201502046", 
"201502047", "201502048", "201502049", "201502050", "201502051", 
"201502054", "201502055", "201502057", "201502058", "201502059", 
"201502060", "201502061", "201502062", "201502063", "201502064", 
"201502065", "201502066", "201502067", "201502068", "201502069", 
"201502070", "201502072", "201502073", "201502074", "201502075", 
"201502076", "201502077", "201502078", "201502079", "201502080", 
"201502081", "201502085", "201502086", "201502087", "201502088", 
"201502089", "201502090", "201502091", "201502092", "201502093", 
"201502095", "201502096", "201502097", "201502098", "201502099", 
"201502100", "201502101", "201502102", "201502103", "201502104", 
"201502105", "201502106", "201502107", "201502108", "201502109", 
"201502110", "201502111", "201502112", "201502113", "201502114", 
"201502115", "201502116", "201502117", "201502118", "201502119", 
"201502120", "201502121", "201502122", "201502124", "201502126", 
"201502127", "201502128", "201502129", "201502130", "201502131", 
"201502132", "201502133", "201502134", "201502135", "201502136", 
"201502137", "201502138", "201502142", "201502144", "201502145", 
"201502146", "201502149", "201502150", "201502153", "201502154", 
"201502155", "201502156", "201502158", "201502159", "201502164", 
"201502165", "201502167", "201502175", "201502176", "201502182", 
"201502183", "201502184", "201502185", "201502186", "201502187", 
"201502188", "201502189", "201502190", "201502191", "201502192", 
"201502193", "201502194", "201502195", "201502196", "201502197", 
"201502198", "201502199", "201502200", "201502201", "201502202", 
"201502203", "201502204", "201503014", "201503015", "201503017", 
"201503018", "201503019", "201503020", "201503021", "201503022", 
"201503023", "201503024", "201503025", "201503028", "201503029", 
"201503031", "201503032", "201503033", "201503034", "201503035", 
"201503036", "201503037", "201503038", "201503039", "201503040", 
"201503041", "201503042", "201503044", "201503045", "201503046", 
"201503047", "201503048", "201503049", "201503050", "201503051", 
"201503052", "201503053", "201503054", "201503055", "201503057", 
"201503058", "201503060", "201503061", "201503062", "201503066", 
"201503067", "201503068", "201503069", "201503070", "201503071", 
"201503072", "201503073", "201503074", "201503075", "201503076", 
"201503077", "201503078", "201503079", "201503080", "201503081", 
"201503082", "201503084", "201503085", "201503086", "201503087", 
"201503088", "201503089", "201503090", "201503091", "201503092", 
"201503093", "201503094", "201503096", "201503097", "201503098", 
"201503099", "201503100", "201503101", "201503102", "201503103", 
"201503104", "201503105", "201503106", "201503108", "201503109", 
"201503112", "201503113", "201503114", "201503115", "201503116", 
"201503117", "201503118", "201503119", "201503120", "201503121", 
"201503122", "201503123", "201503125", "201503129", "201503131", 
"201503132", "201503135", "201503136", "201503137", "201503138", 
"201503142", "201503143", "201503144", "201503145", "201503146", 
"201503147", "201503148", "201503149", "201503150", "201503151", 
"201503152", "201503153", "201503157", "201503159", "201503164", 
"201503165", "201503166", "201503167", "201503168", "201503169", 
"201503172", "201503173", "201503174", "201503175", "201503179", 
"201503180", "201503182", "201503183", "201503184", "201503186", 
"201503187", "201503188", "201503190", "201503191", "201503192", 
"201503194", "201503195", "201503196", "201503197", "201503199", 
"201503200", "201503201", "201503202", "201503203", "201503204", 
"201503205", "201503206", "201503210", "201503211", "201503212", 
"201503218", "201503219"), class = "factor"), Length = c(117.5, 
42.5, 47.5, 32.5, 57.5, 62.5, 37.5, 102.5, 117.5, 82.5, 122.5, 
92.5, 52.5, 127.5, 57.5, 107.5, 102.5, 122.5, 37.5, 22.5, 97.5, 
77.5, 72.5, 137.5, 97.5), Number_com = c(27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 10, 3, 0, 12, 0, 17, 5, 48, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 4, 2), Number_survey = c(3, 
2, 2, 1, 12, 25, 22, 8, 4, 12, 1, 1, 144, 13, 7, 4, 3, 16, 38, 
1, 6, 1, 15, 0, 0)), .Names = c("StationID", "Length", "Number_com", 
"Number_survey"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -25L), vars = list(StationID), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    4L, 9L, 24L, 0L, 15L, 22L, 23L, 14L, 10L, 3L, 12L, 16L, 11L, 
    6L, 18L, 13L, 1L, 5L, 21L, 7L, 19L, 17L, 20L, 2L, 8L), group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    StationID = structure(c(51L, 53L, 66L, 94L, 95L, 99L, 105L, 
    124L, 128L, 133L, 146L, 176L, 222L, 237L, 247L, 249L, 315L, 
    322L, 330L, 368L, 383L, 403L, 404L, 421L, 441L), .Label = c("201501002", 
    "201501003", "201501004", "201501005", "201501008", "201501009", 
    "201501010", "201501011", "201501012", "201501013", "201501014", 
    "201501015", "201501016", "201501017", "201501018", "201501019", 
    "201501020", "201501023", "201501024", "201501025", "201501026", 
    "201501027", "201501029", "201501030", "201501031", "201501033", 
    "201501034", "201501035", "201501036", "201501037", "201501038", 
    "201501039", "201501040", "201501042", "201501043", "201501044", 
    "201501045", "201501046", "201501047", "201501048", "201501049", 
    "201501050", "201501051", "201501052", "201501053", "201501054", 
    "201501055", "201501056", "201501057", "201501058", "201501059", 
    "201501060", "201501061", "201501062", "201501063", "201501066", 
    "201501067", "201501068", "201501069", "201501070", "201501071", 
    "201501072", "201501073", "201501074", "201501078", "201501079", 
    "201501080", "201501081", "201501082", "201501083", "201501084", 
    "201501086", "201501087", "201501088", "201501089", "201501090", 
    "201501091", "201501092", "201501094", "201501095", "201501098", 
    "201501099", "201501100", "201501101", "201501103", "201501105", 
    "201501107", "201501108", "201501110", "201501111", "201501112", 
    "201501117", "201501118", "201501119", "201501120", "201501122", 
    "201501123", "201501125", "201501128", "201501129", "201501130", 
    "201501133", "201501134", "201501137", "201501141", "201501142", 
    "201501143", "201501144", "201501145", "201501146", "201501147", 
    "201501150", "201501151", "201501152", "201501153", "201501155", 
    "201501158", "201501159", "201501160", "201501161", "201501162", 
    "201501163", "201501166", "201501172", "201501173", "201501174", 
    "201501175", "201501179", "201501180", "201501181", "201501182", 
    "201501184", "201501185", "201501186", "201501187", "201501188", 
    "201501189", "201501190", "201501191", "201501192", "201501196", 
    "201501197", "201501198", "201501199", "201501200", "201501201", 
    "201501202", "201501203", "201501206", "201502001", "201502002", 
    "201502003", "201502004", "201502005", "201502006", "201502011", 
    "201502013", "201502014", "201502015", "201502016", "201502017", 
    "201502019", "201502020", "201502021", "201502022", "201502023", 
    "201502024", "201502025", "201502026", "201502027", "201502028", 
    "201502029", "201502030", "201502031", "201502032", "201502033", 
    "201502034", "201502037", "201502038", "201502039", "201502040", 
    "201502041", "201502043", "201502044", "201502045", "201502046", 
    "201502047", "201502048", "201502049", "201502050", "201502051", 
    "201502054", "201502055", "201502057", "201502058", "201502059", 
    "201502060", "201502061", "201502062", "201502063", "201502064", 
    "201502065", "201502066", "201502067", "201502068", "201502069", 
    "201502070", "201502072", "201502073", "201502074", "201502075", 
    "201502076", "201502077", "201502078", "201502079", "201502080", 
    "201502081", "201502085", "201502086", "201502087", "201502088", 
    "201502089", "201502090", "201502091", "201502092", "201502093", 
    "201502095", "201502096", "201502097", "201502098", "201502099", 
    "201502100", "201502101", "201502102", "201502103", "201502104", 
    "201502105", "201502106", "201502107", "201502108", "201502109", 
    "201502110", "201502111", "201502112", "201502113", "201502114", 
    "201502115", "201502116", "201502117", "201502118", "201502119", 
    "201502120", "201502121", "201502122", "201502124", "201502126", 
    "201502127", "201502128", "201502129", "201502130", "201502131", 
    "201502132", "201502133", "201502134", "201502135", "201502136", 
    "201502137", "201502138", "201502142", "201502144", "201502145", 
    "201502146", "201502149", "201502150", "201502153", "201502154", 
    "201502155", "201502156", "201502158", "201502159", "201502164", 
    "201502165", "201502167", "201502175", "201502176", "201502182", 
    "201502183", "201502184", "201502185", "201502186", "201502187", 
    "201502188", "201502189", "201502190", "201502191", "201502192", 
    "201502193", "201502194", "201502195", "201502196", "201502197", 
    "201502198", "201502199", "201502200", "201502201", "201502202", 
    "201502203", "201502204", "201503014", "201503015", "201503017", 
    "201503018", "201503019", "201503020", "201503021", "201503022", 
    "201503023", "201503024", "201503025", "201503028", "201503029", 
    "201503031", "201503032", "201503033", "201503034", "201503035", 
    "201503036", "201503037", "201503038", "201503039", "201503040", 
    "201503041", "201503042", "201503044", "201503045", "201503046", 
    "201503047", "201503048", "201503049", "201503050", "201503051", 
    "201503052", "201503053", "201503054", "201503055", "201503057", 
    "201503058", "201503060", "201503061", "201503062", "201503066", 
    "201503067", "201503068", "201503069", "201503070", "201503071", 
    "201503072", "201503073", "201503074", "201503075", "201503076", 
    "201503077", "201503078", "201503079", "201503080", "201503081", 
    "201503082", "201503084", "201503085", "201503086", "201503087", 
    "201503088", "201503089", "201503090", "201503091", "201503092", 
    "201503093", "201503094", "201503096", "201503097", "201503098", 
    "201503099", "201503100", "201503101", "201503102", "201503103", 
    "201503104", "201503105", "201503106", "201503108", "201503109", 
    "201503112", "201503113", "201503114", "201503115", "201503116", 
    "201503117", "201503118", "201503119", "201503120", "201503121", 
    "201503122", "201503123", "201503125", "201503129", "201503131", 
    "201503132", "201503135", "201503136", "201503137", "201503138", 
    "201503142", "201503143", "201503144", "201503145", "201503146", 
    "201503147", "201503148", "201503149", "201503150", "201503151", 
    "201503152", "201503153", "201503157", "201503159", "201503164", 
    "201503165", "201503166", "201503167", "201503168", "201503169", 
    "201503172", "201503173", "201503174", "201503175", "201503179", 
    "201503180", "201503182", "201503183", "201503184", "201503186", 
    "201503187", "201503188", "201503190", "201503191", "201503192", 
    "201503194", "201503195", "201503196", "201503197", "201503199", 
    "201503200", "201503201", "201503202", "201503203", "201503204", 
    "201503205", "201503206", "201503210", "201503211", "201503212", 
    "201503218", "201503219"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), .Names = "StationID", vars = list(StationID)))
```

Code from trawlfunctions by Arthur Millar used in the nonlinear model

```
hood3par=function(x,catch) {
  lenclass=catch[,2]; nwide=catch[,3]; nfine=catch[,3]
  expo=exp(x[1]+x[2]*lenclass)
  cselect=x[3]*expo/( (1-x[3]) + expo)
  -sum( nwide*log(cselect) + nfine*log(1-cselect) ) }
```

Nonlinear model.  Data arguement left blank because it is a . in the code below.

```
nlm(hood3par,p=x,iterlim=300, data =   )
```

## starting values  for model

```
x<-c(-11,0.1,0.65)
```

## dplyr example using do

```
#model
models <- sample_d %>% do(mod = nlm(hood3par,p=x,iterlim=300, data = .))
models
```

## Error message

Error in f(x, ...) : 
  unused argument (data = list(StationID = 51, Length = 57.5, Number_com = 0, Number_survey = 12))

It seems to me that the error message indicates that the data are not being used.

R and computer information:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] datasets  utils     stats     graphics  grDevices methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] nlme_3.1-120        plotrix_3.5-12      reshape2_1.4.1     
 [4] reshape_0.8.5       qpcR_1.4-0          Matrix_1.2-1       
 [7] robustbase_0.92-5   rgl_0.95.1435       minpack.lm_1.2-0   
[10] lmtest_0.9-34       zoo_1.7-12          dplyr_0.4.2        
[13] plyr_1.8.3          MASS_7.3-40         RODBC_1.3-12       
[16] latticeExtra_0.6-26 RColorBrewer_1.1-2  lattice_0.20-31    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.6     magrittr_1.5    R6_2.1.0       
 [4] stringr_1.0.0   tools_3.2.1     parallel_3.2.1 
 [7] grid_3.2.1      DBI_0.3.1       lazyeval_0.1.10
[10] assertthat_0.1  stringi_0.5-5   DEoptimR_1.0-4
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Problem seems to be with `nlm` invocation, which does not have a `data` argument?

Comment: models <- sample_d %>% do(mod = nlm(hood3par,p=x,iterlim=300), data = .)       Error in do_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
         argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Comment: `hood3par` takes two arguments, `x` and `catch`, where do you define those as input? You just pass a `data` argument which `hoodpar` doesn't take..

Comment: I define x ( under starting values for model above) outside of the loop function, but did not define catch.  I thought when the data argument was specified in the do call that that would cover it. Do I need to have x and catch defined with the do function or do I need to have both defined outside of the call?